# Graph search by pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path-finding

Could you please give the direction where I could learn about how to search in graph by some pattern.

I have some unidirectional graph with unique ID and it's type, example A, B, C.

I need to search all ID's accordance to pattern. For example

Search (`A`, `B`, `C`) should return all ID's in case if node types connected in this direction. Return could be as `[1,4,6]` `[4,6,8]`, etc.

Bfs and dfs could help when I am looking some certain type of node, but how could I search if I have a pattern with connections between those nodes.

My test looks like this:

```
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex1 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(1, "A");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex2 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(2, "B");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex3 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(3, "D");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex4 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(4, "A");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex5 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(5, "C");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex6 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(6, "B");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex7 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(7, "E");
Vertex<Integer, String> vertex8 = new Vertex<Integer, String>(8, "C");


vertex1.setNeighbors(Collections.singletonList(vertex2));
vertex2.setNeighbors(Arrays.asList(vertex3, vertex5));
vertex3.setNeighbors(Collections.singletonList(vertex2));
vertex4.setNeighbors(Arrays.asList(vertex5, vertex6, vertex7));
vertex5.setNeighbors(Arrays.asList(vertex2, vertex4, vertex6));
// vertex5.setNeighbors(Arrays.asList(vertex2, vertex3, vertex4, vertex6));
vertex6.setNeighbors(Arrays.asList(vertex4, vertex5, vertex8));
vertex7.setNeighbors(Collections.singletonList(vertex4));
vertex8.setNeighbors(Collections.singletonList(vertex6));

List<List<String>> expectedAnswers = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
answer.add("1");
answer.add("2");
answer.add("5");
expectedAnswers.add(answer);
answer = new ArrayList<String>();
answer.add("4");
answer.add("6");
answer.add("5");
expectedAnswers.add(answer);
answer = new ArrayList<String>();
answer.add("4");
answer.add("6");
answer.add("8");
expectedAnswers.add(answer);

List<String> typePattern = new ArrayList<String>();
typePattern.add("A");
typePattern.add("B");
typePattern.add("C");
// typePattern.add("D");


Graph<Integer, String> graph = new Graph<Integer, String>();
List<List<String>> resutls = graph.search(vertex1, typePattern);

assertResults(resutls, expectedAnswers);
```

Comment: I think that code ([mcve] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it. Add code for graph, test case data and expected result.

Comment: added some test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your example:

- Use BFS or DFS to find all A's. Add any 'A' found to some container C1.
- For each element in C1, check if it has 'B' neighbors. Add any 'AB' path found to C2.
- For each element in C2, check if its last node has 'C' neighbors. Add any 'ABC' path found to C3.
- Report all elements in C3

Comment: 1. I thought about bfs and dfs, however I realized that I don't really need that algorithms in order to find all A's. I can just loop over all nodes, marking each of them as visited. Do you see any difference? In both cases I need to explore each node at least once.

2. When you are saying add AB path to C2. What do you mean by saying path? 3. One more thing, I don't know what is the A and what is the B, I am receiving just list of types in correct order.

Comment: Depending on how you store your graph, you may be able to iterate over all the vertices. If so - of course, you don't need BFS or DFS at the first step.

Comment: A path is a connected sequence of vertices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your 3rd point. Isn't a type attached to each vertex?

Comment: 3 question is not correct, sorry. However I don't know how many items I have in pattern. It might be pattern ABCDE or AB.So I don't reallly understand how I can store in C containers as you described. I need graph structure that have search method that could find be some pattern which consist of x elements.

Comment: Of course. You just need to repeat step 2 or 3 (they are identical) for each element in the pattern. You don't need a graph structure. You only need to keep set of paths ( =  a set of a (sequence of vertex Ids)) at each step.

Comment: didn't really realized it yet. will try to write it

Comment: Both paths are valid assignments, so add both to the set (you should keep a set of sequence of vertex Ids, not a set of sequence of types).

Comment: I can't because I am in loop at this moment, i can't modify collection

Comment: Create a separate collection in each stage. Alternatively - use a Queue instead of a loop.

Comment: I have added my code. Could you please take a look. How Could I remove this hardcoded part pattern.get(1) ...